# How come Logs-Odds Scoring Matrix is symmetric?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am studying Pevsner's Bioinformatics.

It is stated that Logs-Odds Scoring Matrix is symmetric at page 89.

But with given the equation to calculate the cells of the matrix, I find different scores for from cysteine to leucine and for from leucine to cysteine.

How is this possible?
Do we take the lowest value?